# Mongodb deployment best practice for dual nodes?

Tags: mongodb, deployment

I have two nodes and I'd like to deploy mongodb on them. It seems there're two methods:

1. Deploy as master-slave. But it's marked in the official document as "legacy".
2. Deploy as a replica set. But a 2-node replica may not function well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is "off topic" as StackOverflow is for "programming" related questions. Database configuration and administration belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). But really, read the documentation further. 2 nodes is not a redundant set-up. 3 nodes are minimal. You can get away with a relatively small instance if your read the documentation that is.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thx. I'll move this question there.